# I can not connect spyder3 to a python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, spyder

I have tried using Tools-Preferences-Python Interpreter to point it to the local venv, but it gives me an error "you selected an invalid python interpreter". I am using spyder 3.1.4. The virtual environment is based on python3.

Comment: Are you calling Spyder from the correct directory?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to select a valid Python interpreter inside your virtualenv for that setting to take effect (e.g. `/usr/bin/python3` on Linux).

It seems you're not selecting a valid interpreter or you're merely selecting the directory of the virtualenv. That's why that setting is not taking effect.

Comment: I am pointing to /pyvenv/bin/python3. It is actually a link to another install location on the network. This is how the virtual environment created the data structure.

Comment: I think we don't accept symlinks for Python interpreters. Please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) if you want this solved in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the help